# new product type image of bundled product - price_index not insert into catalog_product_entity

Tags: magento-1.7, ecomdev-phpunit

I created a new product type image of bundled product and everything is work except the children product cannot insert the price into database table salt_flat_quote_item and sale_flat_order_item. This turned out to give some problems in the order in the backend cannot show children price of this product but I found the reason is because my new product type cannot insert eav **price_type** into table catalog_product_entity_int then I test to insert this data in the table by manual and child price of the product insert into table salt_flat_quote_item successful. I don't know how to insert this attribute into table catalog_product_entity_int, anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1):

To insert values into the table `catalog_product_entity_int` you have to create a new catalog product attribute of type text (varchar) and then migrate that to a type int manually by running an upgrade script:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', '<<your_attribute_code>>', array(
   'backend_type'    => 'int',
));
$this->endSetup();
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664035/magento-create-product-attribute-that-is-an-integer